# S6 Android OpenGL Compilation Failing When Creating Shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, samsung-mobile

I am trying to make a simple Android game using OpenGL and it was going pretty smoothly until recently. I was able to build and run the application on a s7 and a Nexus 5 emulator but my attempts to run it on my s6 fail.

It seemed that the shader was failing to compile. I am not sure what is causing this issue. I have looked over and tinkered with numerous small things but with no luck. I figure I must be missing something obvious. I have read other answers but they don't seem to apply to a game that is already working on other devices. Below is my shader code and the simple opengl functions.

```
public Shader(String data, int kind) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    this.kind = kind;
    shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(kind);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, data);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    int[] compiled = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
    if (compiled[0] == GLES20.GL_FALSE) {
        String log = GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader);
        dispose();
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Shader compilation error: " + log);
    }
}
```

And here are the openGL functions for shading.

```
public static final String VERT_SHADER =
    "#version 100\n" +

    "uniform float surfaceRatio;\n" +
    "attribute vec2 position;\n" +

    "void main() {\n" +
    "   gl_Position = vec4(position.x * surfaceRatio, position.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);\n" +
    "}\n";

// The fragment shader code.
public static final String FRAG_SHADER =
    "#version 100\n" +

    "uniform vec3 color;\n" +

    "void main() {\n" +
    "   gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0f);\n" +
    "}\n";
```

Let me know if there is something obvious I am missing that would cause these cross platform issues. I can provide more code or information as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your floating point constant syntax is invalid in GLSL ES 1.00. The `f` postfix is not part of the allowed syntax. So everywhere you have `0.0f` in the shader code, you need to replace it by `0.0`, where you have `1.0f` it needs to be `1.0`, and so on.

GLSL compilers from some vendors (that shall remain unnamed...) tend to be relatively lenient, and compile shaders with these kinds of errors without any complaints. Compilers by other vendors are more strict about reporting errors for non-compliant code, as they should.

The `f` postfix is legal in GLSL ES 3.00 and later.

It's important to understand that for example `1.0` is a constant of type `float` in GLSL, unlike in C/C++, where it is a constant of type `double`. So while later GLSL versions allow the `f` postfix, it has absolutely no function, since it does not change the type of the constant.

No version of GLSL ES (up to the current 3.2) supports double values. Only full OpenGL 4.x supports double precision arithmetic in shaders. In OpenGL 4.x, a postfix of `lf` or `LF` is needed for constants of type `double`. Constants without a postfix are still of type `float`.

Comment: I tried this earlier and the error then revolved around the color variable in the shader. Is there potential for an issue there as well? I can provide the specific error text later. I am currently away from my terminal. Thanks for your help. This was super informative.